# Wikipedia long opensearch description

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I use the Wikipedia API, for searching after a special search term.
Like in this example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=pizza&limit=1&namespace=0&format=xml

In this example i have a Description as result. But the description is to short for me.
Can i influence the length of the description, to get a larger description as result?

Comment: Should that description show the part of the article that matched your search term, or should it always be the introduction of the article (even if it was some other part of it that matched).

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that with the `opensearch` action. But if you instead use the action `query` you can have `search` as a generator and ask for `props=extract`. Then you can limit on either number of characters or sentences. Example: https://en.wikipedia.org//w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=xml&exchars=1000&exlimit=1&explaintext=&generator=search&gsrsearch=pizza&gsrlimit=1